# Show that the cut plane $\mathbb{C}$\ $ \left ( -\infty ,0 \right ) $ is starlike.

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: Show that the cut plane $\mathbb{C}$\  $ \left ( -\infty ,0 \right ) $ is starlike.

Attempt: I've thought of arguing that the point 1+0$i$ is a star centre by constructing the line segment joining it to any arbitrary point $z$ in the cut plane. I got $w$= t$z$+(1-t) for some $t \in [0,1]$ for any point $w$ on the line segment. I'm not sure how to proceed though... thought of showing that such line segment will 1) never cross the origin 2) and consist of $w$ of the form -x+0$i$ = -x to fulfill the requirements of it being a star centre but I'm stuck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $w$ to be outside your region, it needs to have both

- Zero imaginary part
- Negative real part

Show that this cannot happen for any $t\in [0,1]$ (you might have to do real $z$ and non-real $z$ in two separate cases).

For non-real $z$, there is only one value of $t$ that gives zero imaginary part. And for that value of $t$, $w$ clearly cannot have negative real part.

For real $z$, we have $z\in [0, \infty)$, and thus the interval $[z, 1]$ (or $[1, z]$ if $z> 1$) clearly contains no negative numbers.